# Unexpected output in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am beginner to javascript and i am getting unexpected output

here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function add(a,b)
        {
            x = a+b;
            return x;
        }
        var num1 = prompt("what is your no.");
        var num2 = prompt("what is another no.")

        alert(add(num1,num2));


    </script>
```

it should give output as a sum of two number entered by us on prompting but it is simply concatenating the two number and popping the output

Comment: In addition to the answers provided, just `+a + +b` should also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `prompt` function returns a `String` and not a `Number`. So what you're actually doing is to request 2 strings and then concatenate them. If you want to add the two numbers together you'll have to convert the strings to numbers:

```
var num1 = parseFloat(prompt("what is your no."));
var num2 = parseFloat(prompt("what is another no."));
```

or simpler:

```
var num1 = +prompt("what is your no.");
var num2 = +prompt("what is another no.");
```

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` returns a string, not a number. `+` is used as both an addition and *concatenation* operator. Use `parseInt` to turn strings into numbers using a specified radix (number base), or `parseFloat` if they're meant to have a fractional part (`parseFloat` works only in decimal). E.g.:

```
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("what is your no."), 10);
//                                   radix -----^
```

or

```
var num1 = parseFloat(prompt("what is your no."));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already provided answers: If you're using parseInt() / parseFloat(), make sure to check if the input in fact was a valid integer or float:

```
function promptForFloat(caption) {
    while (true) {
        var f = parseFloat(prompt(caption));
        if (isNaN(f)) {
            alert('Please insert a valid number!');
        } else {
            return f;
        }
    }
}

var num1 = promptForFloat('what is your no.');
// ...
```

Comment: var num1 = promptForFloat('what is your no.'); here  we are specifying that user should enter a number if he mistakenly entered a string in that prompt we should have a catch to handle this exception

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean -- if you don't want the function to keep asking, just remove the while() loop and throw an exception instead of doing the alert().

Answer (score 1):

When you prompt the user, the return value is a string, normal text.

You should convert the strings in numbers:

```
alert(add(parseInt(num1), parseInt(num2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `prompt` is a string. So your `add` function performs the `+` operator on 2 strings, thus concatenating them. Convert your inputs to `int` first to have the correct result.

```
    function add(a,b)
    {
        x = parseInt( a ) + parseInt( b );
        return x;
    }
```